# fabric Import Error: cannot import name 'isMappingType'

Tags: python, django, fabric

I came across this "ImportError: cannot import name 'isMappingType' " in the middle of process to deploy fabfile for a Django Project.

1.Here is the structure of my fabfile.py

```
from __future__ import with_statement
from fabric.api import *
from fabric.contrib.console import confirm
from fabric.contrib.files import append, exists, sed

env.hosts = ["127.0.0.1"]

env.user = raw_input('Please enter user:')

def deploy():
      sudo("apt-get update -y")
sudo("apt-get install git -y")
sudo("apt-get install postgresql libpq-dev python-dev python-pip -y")

code_dir = 'backend-directory'

if exists(code_dir):
   run('cd %s && git pull' % (code_dir,)) 
else:
   run("git clone git://serveraddress/projects/backend-directory")


with cd(code_dir):
  sudo("pip install virtualenv")
  run("virtualenv -p /usr/bin/python3.4 venv")
  run("source venv/bin/activate")
  #sudo("pip install -r requirements/dev.txt")
  sudo("pip install -r requirements/production.txt")

  with settings(warn_only=True):
    with settings(sudo_user = 'postgres'):
        sudo("psql -c " + '"CREATE USER new_user WITH PASSWORD ' + "'new_password';" + '"')
        sudo("psql -c 'ALTER USER new_user CREATEDB;'")
        sudo("psql -c 'CREATE DATABASE newdb;'")
        sudo("psql -c 'GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE 'newdb' to new_user;'")

    if run("nginx -v").failed:
        sudo(" apt-get install nginx -y")

code_dir = 'frontend-directory' 

if exists(code_dir):
   run('cd %s && git pull' % (code_dir,)) 
else:
   run("git clone git://serveraddress/frontend-directory")


code_dir = 'backend-directory/project_site'

with cd(code_dir):

    run("python manage.py makemigrations --settings=project.settings.development")
    run("python manage.py migrate --settings=project.settings.development")
    sudo("/etc/init.d/nginx start")

    with settings(warn_only=True):
      if run("find /etc/uwsgi").failed:
          sudo("mkdir /etc/uwsgi")
      if run("find /etc/uwsgi/vassals").failed:
          sudo("mkdir /etc/uwsgi/vassals")
      if run("find /etc/uwsgi/vassals/pam_uwsgi.ini").failed:
          sudo("ln -s ~/backend-direcoty/project_site/pam_uwsgi.ini /etc/uwsgi/vassals/") 

    run("uwsgi --emperor /etc/uwsgi/vassals --uid www-data --gid www-data")
```

Next, I have executed the below command in virtual env

```
(venv)praneeth@praneeth-Latitude-E6400 ~/wru-pam $ fab deploy
```

I got the following traceback:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/bin/fab", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Fabric==1.10.1', 'console_scripts', 'fab')()
  File "/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 474, in load_entry_point
    return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
  File "/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2582, in load_entry_point
    return ep.load()
  File "/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2265, in load
    return self._load()
  File "/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2268, in _load
    module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
  File "/home/praneeth/wru-pam/venv/lib/python3.4/site-packages/fabric/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    from operator import isMappingType
ImportError: cannot import name 'isMappingType'
```

What might be the reason for this import error ?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

[`fabric` *doesn't support Python 3*](https://github.com/fabric/fabric):

> Fabric is a Python (2.5-2.7) library and command-line tool for
>   streamlining the use of SSH for application deployment or systems
>   administration tasks.

See also other points and workarounds at:

- [Python 3 support for fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736274/python-3-support-for-fabric)
- [python3 compatibility?](https://github.com/fabric/fabric/issues/1017)

From what I understand, migrating to [`invoke`](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke) is the first thing to consider.

---

Quick test demonstrating the problem:

```
$ python2.7
>>> from operator import isMappingType
>>>

$ python3.4
>>> from operator import isMappingType
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name 'isMappingType'
```

Comment: would you recommend to deactivate my virtualenvironment which is python 3.x and run the command $ fab deploy

Comment: I simiply deactivated the virtualenvironment which python 3.x version and it looks smooth now thanks

Comment: @Praneeth yeah, it's either you continue with `fabric` on `Python 2.x`, or move to `invoke` on `Python 3.x`. Thanks.

Answer (score 33):

Until Python 3 implementation of fabric is released, you can also use any of the available forks.

One of them is available in **`fabric3`** pip package, which is compatible with Python 3:

Install it with `pip install fabric3` or `pip3 install fabric3`

> - [Fabric3 on GitHub](https://github.com/mathiasertl/fabric/)
> - [Fabric3 in Python Package Index](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Fabric3)

*This is also mentioned in one of the answers in the following question: [Python 3 support for fabric](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18736274/python-3-support-for-fabric)*

I personally use it in a Pelican blog that uses fabric to build or serve the site. It works flawlessly for now.

Comment: Note that fabric3 is a non-official fork that might get abandoned soon if not yet. Since this answer was written, fabric2 was released, it's very different from fabric1 and migration is not quite straight-forward but it's definitely an improvement and it does support python3

Answer (score 6):

python2 : pip install fabric
python3 : pip install fabric3

Answer (score -9):

This is how i fixed it,
Remove python3

```
sudo apt-get remove 'python3.*'
```

Install fabric using:

```
pip install fabric
sudo apt-get install fabric
```

I got this error when i ran `fab polish` after it:

*zsh: /usr/local/bin/fab: bad interpreter: /usr/bin/python3: no such file or directory*

Open `/usr/local/bin/fab` in vim as sudo, & change the first line i.e
`#!/usr/bin/python3` to `#!/usr/bin/python2.7`

Save & run fab polish. All good now !